# Proving dominating functions

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

I'm trying to prove that one function $f = (0.5n^2)$ dominates $g = (2n +1650)$ (with n being an element of the real + numbers) at a certain $n$ value and that ever $n$ greater than or equal to the $n$ value $f$ would dominate $g$, and I wasn't sure on how to approach this. I tried to find the value that intercepted the two points and from a graph, I can tell that $f$ increases at a much more rapid pace from then on, but I'm not sure how to continue on after that? I assume I can't just simply let $n =$ intercept value and conclude that $n^2$ function increases more rapidly than a linear $n$ function? Any suggestions on what to do would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE!  Here's a [handy guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to mark up math nicely on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guide:

Let's solve the inequality

$$0.5n^2 \geq 2n + 1650$$

Multiply by $2$:

$$n^2 \geq 4n+3300$$

$$n^2-4n-3300 \geq 0$$

This is a quadratic equation. Try to solve $$n^2-4n-3300=0.$$

Let's the root be $r_1$ and $r_2$ where $r_1 \geq r_2$.

check  that if $n > r_1$, then $0.5n^2 \geq 2n + 1650$